# Error al graficar valores de fecha con matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Estoy probando con Pandas y matplotlib. La primera columna de la Excel son fechas, formato (dd/mm/yy). La lectura de la hoja Excel con Pandas me presenta:

```
0                Fecha      Valor
1  2017-09-11 00:00:00      44.42
2  2017-09-08 00:00:00      44.17
3  2017-09-07 00:00:00      43.86
4  2017-09-06 00:00:00      43.91
```

Al intentar graficar con matplotlib me da el error KeyError: "Fecha" ¿Cómo puedo  conseguir que la fecha importada por Pandas tenga el formato fecha y así poder graficar fechas - valores?

Comment: efuego te recomiendo siempre incluir la etiqueta del el lenguaje (Python) en estos casos, tu pregunta será más visible. Por otro lado, para poder ayudarte sería oportuno que mostraras el código con el que lees el Excel, de lo contrario poco vamos a poder orientarte. Posiblemente no creas o nombras correctamente tu columna... Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resuelto utilizando xlrd

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import xlrd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## archivo de excel

filename = 'cotizaciones.xlsx'

## lectura del archivo excel

df = pd.read_excel("cotizaciones.xlsx")
print df.head()  # imprime los primeros 5 elementos

## muestra la gráfica

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(df['Fecha'], df['Valor'])
plt.show()